# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'" on line 5

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game where I need the program to choose randomly from rock paper or scissors. I decided to create a random number picker as shown below where 1=rock,2=paper,3=scissors.

```
 1      class Program
    {
 2       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 3           var r = new Random();

 4           var myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
 5           int count = myList.Count;

 6           int indexVal = r.Next(count);

 7           int x = Console.WriteLine(myList[indexVal]);

 8           Console.ReadLine();


        }

      
    }
```

But the problem is when I run the code it says

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'

on line 5.
I plan on taking the value of int x and writing switch statements that decide the winner.

I am an absolute beginner at coding and C# so pls help.

Comment: tell me - _what_ do you expect `Console.WriteLine` to return? what do you think x would contain after executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on line 7 (your numbering).. You cannot assign the result of `Console.WriteLine` to an `int` because writing to the console produces nothing in return. Make it:

```
 7           Console.WriteLine(myList[indexVal]);
```

Whenever you're reading the documentation, or looking in intellisense, and you see that a method returns `void` it means "this method does not return any value" - you cannot capture it and assign it to a variable. In other words, methods that return void may not appear on the right hand side of an `=`, or in some place where they need to generate a value that will then be used (e.g. you cannot say `return Console.WriteLine(...)` because no value is generated to be returned

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much (*^_^*), I was breaking my head earlier trying to fix this tyvm